# Find a maximum tree subgraph with given number of edges that is a subgraph of a tree

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, np

So a problem is as follows: you are given a graph which is a tree and the number of edges that you can use. Starting at v1, you choose the edges that go out of any of the verticies that you have already visited.

An example:[image: graph]

In this example the optimal approach is:

```
for k==1 AC -> 5
for k==2 AB BH -> 11
for k==3 AC AB BH -> 16
```

At first i though this is a problem to find the maximum path of length k starting from A, which would be trivial, but the point is you can always choose to go a different way, so that approach did not work.

What i though of so far:

1. Cut the tree at k, and brute force all the possibilites.
2. Calculate the cost of going to an edge for all edges.
   The cost would include the sum of all edges before the edge we are trying to go to divided by the amount of edges you need to add in order to get to that edge.
   From there pick the maximum, for all edges, update the cost, and do it again until you have reached k.

The second approach seems good, but it reminds me a bit of the knapsack problem.

So my question is: is there a better approach for this? Is this problem NP?

EDIT: A counter example for the trimming answer:

[image]

Comment: The decision problem version of this is certainly in NP. Must the root always be included in the subgraph? Otherwise, BH would be the optimal solution for k=1.

Comment: Can the problem be rephrased as "given a tree with non-negative edge weights, find a maximum-weight subgraph of exactly *k* nodes that is also a tree with the same root as the original one"? If so, I think a *k* × #nodes dynamic programming table can be used to solve this.

Comment: Yes, the tree root is always included, the problem can be rephrased as you said, but you can use k+1 nodes. Could you elaborate on the dynamic programming table approach?

Comment: I would if I could figure it out, but I think it's actually a bit more complicated than I initially thought. Still, I think DP is the way to go for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code illustrates a memoisation approach based on the subproblem of computing the max weight from a tree rooted at a certain node.

I think the complexity will be O(kE) where E is the number of edges in the graph (E=n-1 for a tree).

```
edges={}
edges['A']=('B',1),('C',5)
edges['B']=('G',3),('H',10)
edges['C']=('D',2),('E',1),('F',3)

cache={}
def max_weight_subgraph(node,k,used=0):
    """Compute the max weight from a subgraph rooted at node.
    Can use up to k edges.
    Not allowed to use the first used connections from the node."""
    if k==0:
        return 0
    key = node,k,used
    if key in cache:
        return cache[key]
    if node not in edges:
        return 0
    E=edges[node]
    best=0
    if used<len(E):
        child,weight = E[used]
        # Choose the amount r of edges to get from the subgraph at child
        for r in xrange(k):
            # We have k-1-r edges remaining to be used by the rest of the children
            best=max(best,weight+
                     max_weight_subgraph(node,k-1-r,used+1)+
                     max_weight_subgraph(child,r,0))
        # Also consider not using this child at all
        best=max(best,max_weight_subgraph(node,k,used+1))
    cache[key]=best
    return best

for k in range(1,4):
    print k,max_weight_subgraph('A',k)
```

Comment: Tough, the complexity is not O(kE). For example, take the first graph and starting `k=4`. Notice that even if `max_weight_subgraph('B',*,*)` will be called only `k+1` times, `max_weight_subgraph('C',*,*)` will be called `k + k-1 + k-2 + ... + 1` times. So it is not that the function is call only `k` times on each node. The problem still seems to be `NP`. And this solution, in fact, I want to call it **bruteforce**.

Comment: If there was no cache, then this algorithm would be bruteforce taking exponential time.  I believe that the use of a cache should make the complexity much better.  However, I think you are right and I have underestimated the complexity due to the for loop in the function.  My current guess is that it is more like O(k^2E) complexity.